# When a draw occurs when tracking most occurrences in a list how to find element with highest index?

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
lines = ["Pizza", "Vanilla","Los Angeles Pikes","Cookie Washington Tennis Festival","Water Fiesta","Watermelon"]
best= max(set(lines), key=lines.count)
print (best)
```

The code above returns the greatest occurrence of an element in the list, but in case there is a draw, I want it to return the element with the greatest index. So here I want Watermelon to be printed and if anything is added without a break in the tie the highest index of the draw should be printed.

I need a solution with simple basic code like that seen above and without the importing of libraries. If you could help find a good solution for this it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the index normalized to a value greater than the length of the array to the result of `count`. The normalized index will always be less than 1.0, so that it will not affect the first-order comparison, but will guarantee that there are no ties. I would use a small function to do this:

```
lines = ["Pizza", "Vanilla", "Los Angeles Pikes",
         "Cookie Washington Tennis Festival",
         "Water Fiesta", "Watermelon"]
def key(x):
    return lines.count(x) + lines.index(x) / (len(lines) + 1)
best = max(set(lines), key=key)
print(best)
```

While your original code returned lines = `"Los Angeles Pikes"` in my version of Python (because of the way the hashes turned out), the new version returns `"Watermelon"`, as expected.

You can also use a lambda, but I find that a bit harder to read:

```
best = max(set(lines), key=lambda x: lines.count(x) + lines.index(x) / (len(lines) + 1))
```

Comment: Thank for the help! Also just a quick note, you spelled lambda as "lamba".